# Extract specific tag format in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to extract the following tag name from the following string and replace them with null:
e.g.

```
<abc style="color: red; fill: kddsmv">Hello</abc><abc>World</abc>
```

From the avobe string I will get a text return by replacing all the tags and also capture the style informations.
So after applying regex I would get

```
HelloWorld
```

2nd part of the problem is good, if we can extract the

```
style="color: red; fill: kddsmv"
```

this information too.

Looking eagerly for some help.

I was trying initially with this regex:

```
(<([\/abc]+)>)/g
```

Comment: why with only regex? reason? btw, it is not supposed to be handled in such way.

Comment: Hi @Mr_Green My actual requirement is say in a JSON property user enters: Welcome to <abc style = "color: red">StackOverflow</abc>. Then I would render 2 svg strings, namely 'Welcome to' and 'StackOverflow'(in red color). I was planning to remove this tag. render seperate the strings, and add css to the second string.

It would be good if you have any other lead sir

Comment: @downVoters I have updated my requirement in the avobe comment. Please let me know whats good way to achive it then.

Comment: Why do you want to nullify the tag names? (Just let the DOM parser do the job, and use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `<[^\s\/]+([^>]*)>([^<]+)<\/[^>]+>/g` regex but it will not work for nesting tags